# Spark job-failure due to ClosedChannelException (DFSOutputStream.checkClosed)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, avro

I have a spark app.  I'm storing an rdd on hdfs using `saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset`, utilizing the `AvroKeyOutputFormat`.

For large RDDs sometime I get so many `ClosedChannelException` that the app finally aborts.

I read somewhere that setting `hadoopConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", "false");` helps.

Here is how I save my rdd:

```
        hadoopConf.set("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", "false");
        final Job job = Job.getInstance(hadoopConf);            
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outPutPath);
        AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(job, MyClass.SCHEMA$);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(AvroKeyOutputFormat.class);

        rdd                    
                .mapToPair(new PreparePairForDatnum())
                .saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration());
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1765)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$BufferedFileOutputStream$PositionFilter.write(DataFileWriter.java:458)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder$OutputStreamSink.innerWrite(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:216)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder.writeFixed(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:150)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream$DataBlock.writeBlockTo(DataFileStream.java:369)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeBlock(DataFileWriter.java:395)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeIfBlockFull(DataFileWriter.java:340)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:311)
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.write(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.write(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:39)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1036)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1042)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$BufferedFileOutputStream$PositionFilter.write(DataFileWriter.java:458)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder$OutputStreamSink.innerWrite(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:216)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BufferedBinaryEncoder.writeFixed(BufferedBinaryEncoder.java:150)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream$DataBlock.writeBlockTo(DataFileStream.java:369)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.writeBlock(DataFileWriter.java:395)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.sync(DataFileWriter.java:413)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.flush(DataFileWriter.java:422)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.close(DataFileWriter.java:445)
        at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.close(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1043)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1215)
        ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can happen when executor was killed. Look in your logs something like that:

```
2016-07-20 22:00:42,976 | WARN  | org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint | Container container_e10838_1468831508103_1724_01_055482 on host: hostName was preempted.
2016-07-20 22:00:42,977 | ERROR | org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClusterScheduler | Lost executor 6 on hostName: Container container_e10838_1468831508103_1724_01_055482 on host: hostName was preempted.
```

If you found then the executor of your task was preempted by yarn application master. In other words, he was killed and given another run queue. About preemption and yarn scheduling can be found [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/) and [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html).

Comment: I also see this happen when the container is killed because it exceeds memory limits.  But thank you for pointing me to scheduler,etc I have a feeling I need to deal with that next!